# Removing GA from Sites

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

My GA code is being used by some other website, which is spoiling my data.

Is there a way to block that site from my Google Analytics account?

Comment: What evidence do you have that another site is using your Analytics code? And even if someone else is using it, what makes you think it's affecting your stats without it being validated?

Comment: Hi, validation is not an issue, you can try it once it, this can be done. Now, about two site using the same code please check - [link] (www.abcmachines.net) and [link](www.stronghold.in) the 2nd GA code used is same

Answer (score 1):

Please see this [accepted answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/46631/does-google-analytic-count-mismatching-unconfigured-urls/46634#46634), which covers the exact same question with a solution on how to block unwanted traffic in your Google Analytics account.

Comment: This is part of basic setup. All profiles should have this

Comment: Agreed, all profiles SHOULD have this, but in fact, they don't. Most users either don't understand this, forgot to set it up or simply don't care.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't possible because a) you have to validate that you own the url in order to use your GA code and b) the analytics are reported by url anyway so unless you are serving differing content on a given url one won't ever conflict with another.

Comment: Hi James, this is can be done and i can see it in my account.Try it once. i just need way to block those sites.

Comment: James, you can add ANY Google Analytics Property ID to any site you have control over. I could add stackexchange.com's Property ID to my sites if I wanted to, spoiling stackexchange.com's metrics...

Comment: except it doesn't spoil their metrics because it is filtered by url!  don't you think google analytics would be useless if it was so easily tampered with!?

Comment: try it yourself. google does not pre-filter anything if you don't specifically set this up yourself. so, yes, Google Analytics is pretty useless if you don't know what you're doing and someone is tampering with your Profile IDs...